# Following file associations have been restored. They are registered as DDL file types in project

Tags: android, android-studio

Since the latest DB Navigator update (yesterday 2019-11-05) I am getting these error messages:

> Following file associations have been restored: "tpb". They are registered as DDL file types in project "myProyect".
>
> Please remove them from project DDL configuration first (Project Settings > DB Navigator > DDL File Settings)

This error repeats for every DB Navigator extension: tpb, tps, tpe, pkb, pks, pkg, fnc, prc and trg.

I want to solve it, but I can not find this setting or how to remove them.

What I have already tried:

- Searching in File > Settings
- Searching in settings.graddle, local.properties and other setting files.
- DB Navigator > Settings (There is a DDL Files tab, it has a list with all the extensions)

How to remove these file associations from project DDL configuration?

---

2019-11-12 Updated

It seems that v3.2.0564.0 moved the errors to Event log Window, which make them less annoying, Tudro post below says that this is a bug and not a setting.

It seems like there is no solution yet.

---

2019-11-19 Reported to InteliJ

If you are having this issue, you can go to the following link posted by John Bentley and vote to fix this bug:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006619499-DB-Navigator-Following-file-associations-have-been-restored-ext-They-are-registered-as-DDL-file-types-in-project-Project-Name-

---

2019-12-30 Updated to v3.2.0589, the bug still there.

Answer (score 2):

This looks more like a bug in the latest DB Navigator plugin version than a project configuration issue. It has nothing to do with a specific project, as I initially thought, because I get the same annoying messages for any project. I've tried recreating the project, removing any reference to db navigator from project's files, re-installing the plugin but with no luck.
I ended up installing the previous version of the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator/versions - 3.2.0279.0

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade Database Navigator version to v3.2.0564.0

Answer (score 1):

I've logged this as a bug at: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006619499-DB-Navigator-Following-file-associations-have-been-restored-ext-They-are-registered-as-DDL-file-types-in-project-Project-Name-

Comment: Thank you, I followed that thread to show there are more people having this issue.

Comment: Good on you stramin. In the meanwhile I'm using @kkwang's workaround of disabling the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the "Database Navigator" plugin, disable it.